# Exploring GDELT Data Set

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

I am exploring GDELT data set for the first time, trying to figure out what's the best way to source the data. Data from the RAW FILES section https://www.gdeltproject.org/data.html#rawdatafiles is resource crunching, so trying to source the data from Google Big Query. Is there any channel to communicate with Google team who manages this data set? I need specific requirements of the data who is the best point of contact to discuss?

tried querying gdelt-bq.full.events,gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg tables in Big Query environment. It's resource consuming and expensive if the query is not optimized properly. I searching for a team who can help me on exploring this data and tailor the data as per my requirements.